# How can I allow my users to login with Windows credentials?

Tags: java, authentication, windows-authentication

I am creating a (Java-based) web application. How can I allow my users to login with Windows credentials?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The best questions are those that show original research and effort on the part of the asker. This is not a substitute for your favorite search engine. Please do some research and attempt a solution on your own, then ask real questions about actual problems you are facing in the implementation of your solution. [Read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information, or feel free to search [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for questions on appropriate material for your question.

Comment: Have tried to ask same question in Google?

Comment: tried using javascript... but it works only in IE and also browser asks for permission.. also on searchin for the solution, it suggest like kerberos , waffle like that.. i dont have any idea about these..

Comment: Then show your effort in your question. Think of it like partial credit. We have no reason to award users who don't show an attempt to answer the question themselves before coming to us. We're tutors, not solution-writers. That being said, update your question with the code you wrote so that others may help you improve it or point out what's causing any problems you have with it. Also, JavaScript *isn't* Java, so unless your problem deals with Java directly, please change the tags as well. You can edit your question (and tags) by clicking the `edit` button underneath it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Authentication for Java Based web applications, How to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773688/windows-authentication-for-java-based-web-applications-how-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all find out what kind of authentication the windows login uses, like LDAP server etc.
Next get the information about this authentication server.
Next configure this kind of authentication service in your webserver.