# How to integrate java web applications with windows authentication?

Tags: jakarta-ee, active-directory, websphere, single-sign-on, windows-authentication

I have seen one or two solutions on Stackoverflow but i did not find the answer i am looking for.
i have figured out the way to query active directory server but i need to know how to pass windows credentials from the browser to the server.

this is a requirement for my project. i need windows authentication for my java application. i know it's a matter of 3-4 steps with IIS and ASP but it has become a nightmare for me.
please help. 
looking forward for a sleek and simple solution.

**Edit:** I am using following technology stack.

front end: AngularJs
Server end: J2EE (Servlet, JSP and REST)
Server: WAS 6
**Edit:2**

Rephrasing: In IIS and ASP applications IE does not prompt for password. It means IE passess windows credentials to server without prompting. Can i get same stuff with architecture i am using?

Comment: Please post these Q/As that didn't helped you.

Comment: For a real answer, the Java server software and web framework details need to be added to the question. At this point I can only guess that maybe SPNEGO can help. http://spnego.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Luiggi: following are the Q/A. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094217/authenticate-using-windows-user-credentials-java-web-application another one is- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773688/windows-authentication-for-java-based-web-applications-how-to